# Paperclip: Validate/process attachment before upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

Paperclip offers nice validator methods like

```
validates :image, attachment_size: { in 0..2.megabytes }
```

My problem is that attachment files get uploaded to S3 even though the validators would add errors to the attachment hosting object. So if the image is too big it's getting uploaded and the `ActiveRecord`-Object is getting errors on it when validating. That's okay but for my situation it would be more clean to reject uploads that are too big.

Is there a way to tap into the process and prevent a file from being uploaded to S3 under certain conditions?

Currently my implementation cares for the errors and deletes the attachment afterwards if the hosting object is not valid.

The described situation refers to Rails 4.0 application using Ruby 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The described problem does not occur in more recent Paperclip versions (most recent version at the time I'm writing this: 4.2). Files won't be uploaded to S3 when validations have attached errors to the AR-Object then.